# ModelState.AddModelError showing error twice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

With MVC stuff when there is an error on property level, we can add error to `ModelState`
but the same error is added to the summary also. How can we avoid to display it twice.

I want to display only public errors in the message summary and all other at property level.

Regards
Parminder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining your validation summary set the first parameter to true which means `Exclude Property Errors`.

Eg:

```
<%= Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Unable to save item. Please correct the errors and try again.")%>
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.validationextensions.validationsummary(VS.100).aspx):

> excludePropertyErrors Type: System.Boolean
>
> true to have the summary display model-level errors only, or false to have the summary display all errors.